# Save every output of same command in different variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERLABEL=( 11011-22022 33033-44044-10101 55055-10001-20002 )

    for vmlabel in "${SERVERLABEL[@]}"
    do 
        linode-cli linodes list | grep $vmlabel | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
    done
```

Above is my script. What I want to do is save the ipv4 of each VM in different env variable like

```
ipv4_11011-22022
ipv4_33033-44044-10101
ipv4_55055-10001-20002
```

I am new to bash scripting, can someone please help me in this

Comment: Those are not valid shell variable names, because shell variable names cannot contain "-". Also, more generally, trying to put data in your variable names tends to be a mess. Some sort of array is almost always a better idea.

Comment: Ohh.. I didn't knew about this, will change it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using *associative array*:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERLABEL=( 11011-22022 33033-44044-10101 55055-10001-20002 )

declare -A ips # declare an associative array explicitly 

for vmlabel in "${SERVERLABEL[@]}"
do 
    ips[ipv4_$vmlabel]=$(
        linode-cli linodes list |
            grep -F -- "$vmlabel" |
            grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
    )
done
```

#### You can reduce this **HUDGE** regex

```
linode-cli linodes list |
    grep -F -- "$vmlabel" |
    perl -MRegexp::Common -lne 'print for /$RE{net}{IPv4}/g'
```

Far more readable and maintainable, no?

Or even skip `grep` which `perl` is able to do by itself.

```
linode-cli linodes list |
    perl -MRegexp::Common -lnse '
        if (/\Q$vmlabel\E/) {
            print for /$RE{net}{IPv4}/g
        }' -- -vmlabel="$vmlabel"
```

<sup>Going further and doing the whole thing in `perl` (or any proper programming language) instead of `bash` would also make it easier to do a stricter parsing of the output of a *single* invocation of `linode-cli` and make it a lot more reliable and efficient.</sup>

#### Display the fetched datas

```
printf '%s\n' "${!ips[@]}"                     # keys
printf '%s\n' "${ips[@]}"                      # values
printf '%s\n' "${ips[ipv4_55055-10001-20002]}" # display only one key/value pair
```

Beware `grep` or `perl` do a substring match for the `$vmlabel`, so a `grep -F -- 11011-22022` would match on any line containing `11011-22022` including `211011-220221` for instance. You may want to add the `-w` option to `grep` to guard against it.

Comment: ipv4_11011-22022,
ipv4_33033-44044-10101,
ipv4_55055-10001-20002, How can I save the IPs in these variables ?

Comment: Have you understand _associative array_ ? It's an array with the variable name as key. Isn't sufficient ?

Comment: Sir then how can I call the variables? Like if I want to do echo "First VM IP is $ipv4_11011-22022"

Comment: Check my edited post, the last line

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: A further improvement would be to run `linode-cli linodes list` just once, and maybe run a simple Awk script to extract all the nodes of interest.

Comment: I agree. But I dunno what is the output of that command.